# How to Group By Month only where that month is between two record field values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL table with three fields 
CreatedTime (datetime)
RetiredTime (datetime)
Name (varchar)

I would like to create a query for the following:
Take a date range and provide count (group by Month) for each record where ((CreatedTime <= DateInRange) and (RetiredTime >= DateInRange))

Example:
Query parameters (DateRange) Start = 06/01/2013,    End = 12/01/2013

Results:
Month Count
6/2013 5
7/2013 4
8/2013 4
9/2013 8
10/2013 4
11/2013 9
12/2013 12

So there are 8 records that match CreatedTime < 9/2013 AND RetiredTime > 9/2013
Basically it goes through each of the 6 months and returns a count for those that match the criteria.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: but what date are you using in the results?  the createddate or the retiredtime?

Answer (score 0):

Your question makes it unclear what `DATE` column to use for the display so you will have to fill that in.

```
SELECT CAST( DATEPART(mm,DATECOL)  AS VARCHAR(2)) + '/' + CAST( DATEPART(yyyy, DATECOL) AS VARCHAR(4)),
   COUNT(*)
 FROM TABLE
 WHERE CreatedTime < @CreatedTime AND RetiredTime > @RetiredTime
 GROUP BY CAST( DATEPART(mm,DATECOL)  AS VARCHAR(2)) + '/' + CAST( DATEPART(yyyy, DATECOL) AS VARCHAR(4))
 ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: I would like the Date column to contain each month from the Start to End Query parameters (6/2013 - 12/2013). So each record would need to be evaluated against 6/2013, 7/2013, 8/2013... to determine if that date falls between CreatedTime and RetiredTime. Then add to count if True. So evaluating 6/2013 if between CreatedTime and RetiredTime for each record, then evaluating 7/2013 for each and so on... I'm not sure if this is something that cannot be done in a SQL query and requires additional data manipulation with a more generic query.. Thanks!

Comment: This would be similar to running a separate query for each month 6/2013, 7/2013, 8/2013, etc... to provide count of records where that month is between CreationDate and RetiredDate.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you wish to group by Created time, there are many ways to do it, below is my perfered way. If you wish to Group by RetiredTime, simply change the values.

```
SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(CreatedTime), '/', MONTH(CreatedTime)), COUNT(*) FROM TABLENAME
WHERE ((CreatedTime <= DateInRange) and (RetiredTime >= DateInRange))
GROUP BY CONCAT(YEAR(CreatedTime), '/', MONTH(CreatedTime))
```